# Opencv on java that installed via apt showing error on NetBeans

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, apt

I was installed opencv 4 on my machine via apt

[image]

But when I tried on netbeans and import the opencv it's showing error

the error on this line syntax :

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
```

I watch some tutorial should use jar file or import lib directory that was build before, but in my case I installed the opencv via apt , I read this tutorial https://andrefellipe.com/opencv-java.html he installed via apt tho but he got jar file on opencv 3, but in the jar file on opencv 4 doesn't appear

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:
Find all related packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep libopencv
```

You should find this one:

> libopencv4.2-java

Then use:

```
dpkg -L libopencv4.2-java
```

All directory related to it is be found there, including the jar, for me it is in

> /usr/share/java/opencv-420.jar